# Flexslider Carousel is stopping slideshow despite setting pauseOnAction to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have a flexslider with Carousel Nav with the following JS config:

```
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    //pauseOnAction: false, // this is not working
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 4600,
    animationSpeed: 600, 
    pauseOnAction: false,
    sync: "#carousel",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

I do not want the slideshow to stop if a user clicks on the slider, so I added the "pauseOnAction: false" setting. However, if the user clicks on the Carousel items, the slideshow stops. I added the same pauseOnAction config to the Carousel portion, but it does not fix the problem.

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: What version? Is there any particular reason your'e showing us two instances of `flexslider()`?

Comment: It's flexslider 2 and one is for the slider and the other is for the nav-carousel, here is the example: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Comment: did you find any solution for this bug?

Comment: have you tried to add to the init options 
after: function(slider) {
  if (!slider.playing) {
    slider.play();
  }
}

?